# Remove duplicates from an arraylist with strings

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist that looks like this:

`public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>> x = new ArrayList<>();`

I store groups of 2 persons in a pair. For example:

`[Person1, Person2]
[Person3, Person4]`

The algorithm I use right now still makes duplicates, I've tried out hashmaps and iterating through them with for loop but they just give me back the original list.

This is the code:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class createGroups
{
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>> x = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args){
    //Define names
    String[] names = {"Person1", "Person2", "Person3", "Person4"};
    try
    {
        //Create combinations. In a try catch because of the saveFile method.
        combination(names, 0, 2);
        //Print all the pairs in the Arraylist x
        printPairs();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static void combination(String[] data, int offset, int group_size) throws IOException
{
    if(offset >= data.length)
    {
        //Create new Arraylist called foo
        ArrayList<String[]> foo = new ArrayList<>();
        //Create a pair of 2 (data.length = 4 / group_size = 2)
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length / group_size; i++)
        {
            //Add the pair to foo.
            foo.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 2 * i, 2 * (i + 1)));
        }
        //Add foo to x
        x.add(foo);
        //saveFile(foo);
    }

    for(int i = offset; i < data.length; i++){
        for(int j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++){
            swap(data, offset, i);
            swap(data, offset + 1, j);
            combination(data, offset + group_size, group_size);
            swap(data, offset + 1, j);
            swap(data, offset, i);
        }
    }
}

public static void printPairs(){
    //Print all pairs
    for(ArrayList<String[]> q : x){
        for(String[] s : q){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }


}

private static void swap(String[] data, int a, int b){
    //swap the data around.
    String t = data[a];
    data[a] = data[b];
    data[b] = t;
}

}
```

The output right now is this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBC42.png)

Every group of 4 names is a 'list' of pairs (Not really a list but that's what I call it)

And this is the desired output:
[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxvwo.png)

But then you can see that the first and the last list of pairs are basically the same how do I change that in my `combination` method

The question:

> How can I change my `combination` method so that it doesn't create duplicate groups.
>   And how can I make the list smaller (The desired output) when printing the created lists.

If I wasn't clear enough or if I didn't explain what I want very well, let me know. I'll try to make it clearer.

Comment: Post the relevant code here.

Comment: I think you should explain what does "duplicate" mean to you.

Comment: @EganWolf By "duplicate" I mean if you have a,b,c,d that It doesnt do a,b,c,d or c,d,a,b and so on

Comment: You could try to implement your own data object that takes 4 strings (two pairs of persons) and implement hashCode and equals methods according to what you consider identical combinations.

Comment: @MatheM Could you give an example?

Comment: For the extracting the pairs, instead of `i++` do `i +=2`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object similar to this. It takes 4 strings (2 pairs). Puts the strings into array and sorts this array. That means any combination of strings you put in will be converted into one sorted combination, but the object internaly remembers which person is person1, person2, ...

```
private class TwoPairs {
    private final String person1;
    private final String person2;
    private final String person3;
    private final String person4;

    private final String[] persons;

    TwoPairs(String person1, String person2, String person3, String person4) {
        this.person1 = person1;
        this.person2 = person2;
        this.person3 = person3;
        this.person4 = person4;

        persons = new String[4];
        persons[0] = person1;
        persons[1] = person2;
        persons[2] = person3;
        persons[3] = person4;

        // if we sort array of persons it will convert 
        // any input combination into single (sorted) combination

        Arrays.sort(persons); // sort on 4 objects should be fast

        // hashCode and equals will be comparing this sorted array
        // and ignore the actual order of inputs
    }

    // compute hashcode from sorted array
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(persons);
    }

    // objects with equal persons arrays are considered equal
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        TwoPairs other = (TwoPairs) obj;
        if (!Arrays.equals(persons, other.persons)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    // add methods which you might need
    // getters for individual persons
    // String getPerson1() { return person1; }
    // or perhaps pairs of persons
    // String[] getPair1() { return new String[] {person1, person2}; }
    // add sensible toString method if you need it
}
```

Your ArrayList x will change like this

```
ArrayList<TwoPairs> x = new ArrayList<TwoPairs>();
```

before adding new TwoPairs object into x check if this list already contains this object.

```
if (!x.contains(twoPairsObject)) {
    x.add(twoPairsObject);
}
```

Comment: I'll try it out. Thanks